# Problems with Zoho Node.js SDK Authentication

Tags: node.js, zoho

I'm following instructions in the [npmjs.org page for Zoho Node.js SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zohocrm/nodejs-sdk-2.1) to write this code. I running it on windows 10. It's failing when it tries to find the file used in instantiating the FileStore. I'm using the Zoho Self Client method for oAuth2 authentication.  In this code, I just supply them a temporary access token so that I can create a refresh token and then I'll use that in a serverless function to read data from the Zoho CRM. My understanding was that the SDK would write the auth credentials to the Filestore and it would include the refresh token.
This fails at reading the filestore which does exist in the directory.  I'm confused about the filestore, because I thought the SDK would be writing the token to this file, not trying to read it.
If you've worked with Zoho CRM and can see the problem, please share.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS)

import { URL } from 'url'; // in Browser, the URL in native accessible on window

// Will contain trailing slash
const absolute_path = new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname;
console.log("dirname", absolute_path)

import * as ZOHOCRMSDK from '@zohocrm/nodejs-sdk-2.1';

class Initializer {
    static async initialize() {

        /*
         * Create an UserSignature instance that takes user Email as parameter
         */
        let user = new ZOHOCRMSDK.UserSignature(process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

        /*
         * Configure the environment
         * which is of the pattern Domain.Environment
         * Available Domains: USDataCenter, EUDataCenter, INDataCenter, CNDataCenter, AUDataCenter
         * Available Environments: PRODUCTION(), DEVELOPER(), SANDBOX()
         */
        let environment = ZOHOCRMSDK.USDataCenter.PRODUCTION()

        /*
         * Create a Token instance
         * clientId -> OAuth client id.
         * clientSecret -> OAuth client secret.
         * grantToken -> GRANT token.
         * redirectURL -> OAuth redirect URL. Default value is null
         */
        let token = new ZOHOCRMSDK.OAuthBuilder()
            .clientId(process.env.SELF_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID)
            .clientSecret(process.env.SELF_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID)
            .grantToken(process.env.SELF_CLIENT_TEMPORARY_GRANT_TOKEN)
            .redirectURL(process.env.REDIRECT_URL)
            .build();

        /*
         * TokenStore can be any of the following
         * DB Persistence - Create an instance of DBStore
         * File Persistence - Create an instance of FileStore  ** using this to save refresh token
         * Custom Persistence - Create an instance of CustomStore
         */
        const tokenstore_location = `${absolute_path}nodejs_sdk_tokens.txt`
        console.log("tokenstore_location", tokenstore_location)
        let tokenstore = new ZOHOCRMSDK.FileStore(tokenstore_location)


        /*
            * Set the following in InitializeBuilder
            * user -> UserSignature instance required
            * environment -> Environment instance required
            * token -> Token instance required
            * store -> TokenStore instance
            * SDKConfig -> SDKConfig instance
            * resourcePath -> resourcePath
            * logger -> Logger instance. Default value is null
            * requestProxy -> RequestProxy instance. Default value is null
            */
        // The SDK can be initialized by any of the following methods
        (await new ZOHOCRMSDK.InitializeBuilder())
        .user(user)
        .environment(environment)
        .token(token)
        .store(tokenstore)
        .initialize()
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}

Initializer.initialize(); Zoho
```